# Вылетает delete при попытке удалить структуру

Tags: c++, zeromq, delete

Вылетает *delete* при попытке удалить структуру

Есть функция:

```
// Заполнение очереди комманд
void QueleСommandFiller(...) {
    struct MyMessen* mes;
        ...
        // Получение сообщения
        mes = GetMsg(responsSocket);
        // Анализ сообщения (Lasciate ogni speranza, voi ch’entrate)
        if (mes != NULL) {
            CM_Add(mes, cm);
            delete(mes);
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу обратить внимание на функцию:

```
// Получение сообщения
struct MyMessen* GetMsg(void* responsSocket) {
    zmq_msg_t message;
    zmq_msg_init(&message);
    if (zmq_msg_recv(&message, responsSocket, ZMQ_DONTWAIT) == -1) {
        zmq_msg_close(&message);
        return NULL;
    }
    struct MyMessen* mes = (struct MyMessen*) zmq_msg_data(&message);
    zmq_msg_close(&message);
    return mes;
}
```

И

```
// Добавление элементов в очередь
void CM_Add(struct MyMessen* mes, struct CommandQueue* cm) {
    struct CommandQueue_leaf tmp;
    tmp.mes = *mes;
    tmp.status = 0;
    cm->mes.push_back(tmp);
}
```

При вызове delete mes не нулловый, проверил на отладчике.

Но все равно вылетает в

```
extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(void const* const block)
{
    if (!block)
        return FALSE;

    return HeapValidate(__acrt_heap, 0, header_from_block(block));
}
```

P.S. Я смотрю с подозрение на строки:

> struct MyMessen* mes = (struct MyMessen*) zmq_msg_data(&message);

и

> cm->mes.push_back(tmp);

Comment: А почему вы пытаетесь удалять структуру которую не выделяли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь делать `delete` для чего-то, что не было выделено `new`. Результат ожидаем. Откуда у вас вообще возникла идея делать тут `delete`?

Более того, согласно описанию `zmq_msg_data`, она не выделяет никакой памяти вообще, а просто возвращает указатель на некие ресурсы, ассоциированные с объектом `zmq_msg_t message`. Так как `zmq_msg_t message` - локальная переменная в `GetMsg`, и к тому же все связанные с ней ресурсы освобождаются вызовом `zmq_msg_close`, ни о каком возвращении указателя `mes` наружу из `GetMsg` не может быть и речи - это "мертвый" указатель.